# Why isn't there an accepted answers category in the profile?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

In your profile, the answers can be sorted by **votes**, **activity** and time (**newest**).

Is there a reason why there isn't an **[accepted]** category also?

I myself have very few answers, but don't users with hundreds of answers want the ability to only see their answers that are accepted?

Comment: You can use the search functionality. Just type: `user:me isaccepted:yes`

Comment: @user000001 *"Just type..."*, sorry but how can I (or any user for that matter) know that search phrase exactly? Shouldn't this be a part of the profile UI?

Comment: Sure, why not? It comes down to how useful it would be to how many people. I would assume that the people with enough answers for this to be useful are involved in the site enough to be familiar with the search tips in the help center.

Comment: Would that canned search be useful? Sure, like myriad others. Would it be useful enough to clutter the UI? Surely not.